dnd-kit drag handle stops working after toggling visibility
I'm conditionally rendering a drag handle component based on user input, but once its hidden, then shown again, drag n drop stops working. It does handle the click and it seems to think that it's dragging, but the actual dragging does not happen unless I regenerate the data.
I thought this issue was with tanstack table, so I tried without it, but the problem persists.
Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/crazy-montalcini-mc8ckm
From what I've tried it seems like any re-rendering of the handle causes it to break. I tried also resetting the array instance with the same data hoping it would maybe reset the whole sortable list but nothing helped.
Probably the easiest workaround here is to simply set display to none (haven't tried it yet, but should work) but I'd rather not do that since tanstack table (where I need this) has a visibility API precisely for toggling column visibility.
Sorry for the small image, had to resize due to SO restriction.

UPDATE:
It seems like the issue is in SortableContext. I figured since data regeneration fixes the issue, the problem probably isn't in the drag handle so I thought I'd force react to "refresh" the SortableContext by setting a key that always changes like so key={`${Date.now()}`} and it seems to work!
Of course this is a hack so I'd rather not do this but at least it seems like I'm moving in the right direction...
UPDATE 2:
So far I've worked around this issue by exposing a remount function from my table component like so:
// Incrementing this value forces remount of SortableContext.
// See comment for remountSortableContext above.
const [sortableContextKey, setSortableContextKey] = useState(0);

// Expose table ref and other functions to parent. useImperativeHandle works only with forwardRef.
useImperativeHandle(
  ref,
  () => {
    return {
      remountSortableContext() {
        setSortableContextKey(sortableContextKey + 1);
      },
      table
    };
  },
  [sortableContextKey, table]
);

// .....

<SortableContext
  items={identifiers}
  strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
  disabled={!enableDragging}
  key={sortableContextKey}
>
 // stuff
</SortableContext>

Now every time the parent restores drag handle column visibility, it calls remountSortableContext on the table ref and that makes drag n drop work again.
